# WSCONFIG on ColdFusion 11 and ColdFusion 10

Tags: iis, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-10, coldfusion-11

I have a Windows 7 virtual machine that has ColdFusion 9 installed for development and testing. I need ColdFusion 10 and 11 as well for other projects.

ColdFusion 9 is running perfectly, but when I spin up ColdFusion 10 or 11 and try to use WSCONFIG to configure a site in IIS, I get the following list of sites:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/v7mdgha536shk9t/Screenshot%202015-05-21%2023.29.14.png?dl=0

In reality each site in IIS has a separate name and when I delete a the site that each one is named after, in this case "cfadmin", all of the remaining sites show up in WSCONFIG as another one of the site names.

I have never had this problem before. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**Update:**

As suggested in the comments, here are the results when I launched a command prompt as Administrator and ran the suggested command:

> C:\Users>%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd list sites SITE "cfadmin"
>   (id:3,bindings:,state:Unknown) SITE "mccalmon"
>   (id:1,bindings:http/*:80:,state:Unknown) SITE "Virtus"
>   (id:5,bindings:,state:Unknown) SITE "EMSA"
>   (id:9,bindings:,state:Unknown) SITE "Classic"
>   (id:10,bindings:,state:Unknown) SITE "Test"
>   (id:2,bindings:http/*:80:local.test.com,state:Unknown)

Comment: Can you launch Command prompt as Administrator and try the command %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd list sites & share the output?

Comment: C:\Users\>%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd list sites
SITE "cfadmin" (id:3,bindings:,state:Unknown)
SITE "mccalmon" (id:1,bindings:http/*:80:,state:Unknown)
SITE "Virtus" (id:5,bindings:,state:Unknown)
SITE "EMSA" (id:9,bindings:,state:Unknown)
SITE "Classic" (id:10,bindings:,state:Unknown)
SITE "Test" (id:2,bindings:http/*:80:local.test.com,state:Unknown)

Comment: @resonantmedia - FYI, not everyone reads comments. Moved code block above into question, so it is more visible. The redundant comment can be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

All of your site "state" are "**Unknown**". The problem seems to be with your sites only. If appcmd is not able to identify the correct state, then, ColdFusion will definitely not be able to recognize the same. The sites state would be unknown, if the IIS Server is stopped/shut down.

For e.g, my server shows the below information with the "%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd list sites" command.

```
SITE "Default Web Site" (id:1,bindings:http/*:80:,state:Started)
SITE "CF9"  (id:2,bindings:http/*:81:,state:Started)
SITE "CF10" (id:3,bindings:http/*:82:,state:Stoped)
SITE "CF11" (id:3,bindings:http/*:83:,state:Started)
```

You can try IISRESET in command prompt to restart IIS. Then, launch the **Web Server Config tool** as **administrator** and create the connector.